# How to call particular function after every two mins In Blazor razor component?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I want call particular function after every two mins in blazor. I tried following code

```
@using System;
@inherits Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.OwningComponentBase<TestBlazor.Client.APIGateway>

//Html code to display list.

@code{
    private IEnumerable<TestBlazor.Model.Message> MessagesList;

    protected override OnInitialized()
   {

     SetTimer();
   }    

   private void SetTimer()
   {
      var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
      var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

      var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
     {
        GetMessage();
     }, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);
   } 



   private void GetMessage()
  {
    var filter = new TestBlazor.Model.Filter.MessageFilter()
    {
        Origination = Model.Enums.MessageOrigination.Patient,
        PharmacyId = 1
    };

    MessagesList = Service.MessageService.GetFilteredSummaryAsync(filter).Result;
    MessagesList = MessagesList.Select(x => { x.DateTime = DateTime.Now; return x; }).ToList();

    base.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
  }
}
```

This is working as expected but problem is when I navigate to other component and again come back to this Message component then I am getting following exception

**Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Messages'**
where 'Messages' is Razor component name.It will be helpful if anybody could tell me what exactly I am doing wrong? or Is there any other solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your timer continues to run even when the component is already removed from the view. In that case, the timer will just try to access the component instance (because it still has a reference to it), and call the `GetMessage` which will eventually make an operation on the component that will not work because the component has actually been disposed.

What you should do is to make sure that you free up all resources when the component is removed. You can do that [by implementing `IDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1#component-disposal-with-idisposable) with your component. Usually, this would look like this:

```
@implements IDisposable

@code {
     private Timer _timer;

     protected override void OnInitialized()
     {
         _timer = new Timer(…);
     }

     public void Dispose()
     {
         _timer?.Dispose();
     }
}
```

Since your component inherits from `OwningComponentBase` which already implements `IDisposable` itself, you will need to extend the disposal of your component:

```
@inherits OwningComponentBase<TestBlazor.Client.APIGateway>

@code {
     private Timer _timer;

     protected override void OnInitialized()
     {
         _timer = new Timer(…);
     }

     protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
     {
         _timer?.Dispose();
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi Poke,I put timer variable globally and called SetTimer() in OnInitializedAsync.After this I called Dispose function So it's works.Thanks

Comment: This saved an important project. Annoying Timers wouldn't stop ticking even after I left the page and no workaround I found and tried seemed to help.

Answer (score 3):

Code below worked in Blazor Wasam .NET6

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    //set timer
    var timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

    while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
    {
        //do something here every 10s
    }
}
```